# Como ejecutar un comando desde Terminal (MAC) con C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, macos

estoy realizando un proyecto en .NET con C# sobre el entorno de Visual Studio MAC.

necesito ejecutar desde el código en C# una llamada al terminal de mac.
el código que he visto es algo así:

```
 ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() { FileName = "/System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app", Arguments = "echo $path", };
 Process proc = new Process() { StartInfo = startInfo, };
 proc.Start();
```

-> probe con varias opciones:
/Terminal.App
/bin/zsh
/System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app

el error:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Cannot find the specified file
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x000f6] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System/System.Diagnostics/Process.cs:616
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () [0x00032] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs:2001
  at at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
  at visualstudioselenium.MainClass.PDF2IMAGE (System.String filePath) [0x0002d] in /Users/claudioperez/Documents/programacion/legalRobot/visualstudioselenium/Program.cs:59
  at visualstudioselenium.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x000a7] in /Users/claudioperez/Documents/programacion/legalRobot/visualstudioselenium/Program.cs:48
```

Desde ya muchas gracias por su tiempo y ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba agregando la propiedad `UseShellExecute` con valor true:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() { 
        UseShellExecute = true, 
        FileName = "/System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app", 
        Arguments = "echo $path"
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

me funcionó con este código:

```
 public static void ExecuteMacCommand(string command)
        {
            Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/bash";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c \" " + command + " \"";
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.Start();

            while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
            }
        }
```